# At what layer i should determine if something does not exist

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-design

Suppose I have a Comment entity defined as follows:

```
public class comment 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TopicId { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

The TopicId property represents a foreign key referencing the Topics table.

My question is, should I check in my application (using a SELECT query) whether the topic exists before inserting the comment into the database? Alternatively, should I rely on the database constraint and handle the exception that will be thrown if the topic does not exist?

Comment: The later. If you do a check before inserting the database can have changed in between. Handling the case when inserting is a must because of that so the check before hasn't to much of a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Data processing logic should be handled on the database.**

In general, handling this logic at a 'lower' level (closer to the database table representing the entity)

1. **mitigates the risk of external processes affecting your CRUD (Create-Read-Update-Delete) operations**, such as if your database is updated after you perform a SELECT check for the foreign key but before you insert the `comment` entity into the database.
2. **aligns with the principle of 'Separation of Concerns,'** loading the burden of data management onto the 'model' and off of the 'controller' (what you refer to as your 'application'). For more on this principle and the 'Model-View-Controller' architecture, check out today's entry in The Overflow blog: [Model-View-Controller](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/05/17/keep-em-separated-get-better-maintainability-in-web-projects-using-the-model-view-controller-pattern/#:%7E:text=Models%20are%20built%20to%20manage%2C%20hold%20and%20represent%20the%20application%20data)

Comment: Worth adding that in line with MVC architecture it would be the burden of the Service layer to trap any resulting exceptions, such as in the situation described by OP, so the controller can know how to respond accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you check **TopicId** before inserting then it may be possible that the record may exist or not but if exist then you have to call Database two times first validation and then insertion, also you have to code extra for validation,
by relying on Database foreign key constraint, you just have to focus on exception handling.